# PostGIS, create centroid column from polygon column

Tags: postgis

I have a table like this:

```
id|      shape [geometry]     |  centroid [geomety]
---------------------------------------------------
 1|MULTIPOLYGON(((-70, etc...)|
 2|MULTIPOLYGON(((-71, etc...)|
```

I need to create the centroid of each shape, how can I do this? The final result should be this table:

```
id|      shape [geometry]     |  centroid [geomety]
---------------------------------------------------
 1|MULTIPOLYGON(((-70, etc...)|POINT(something)
 2|MULTIPOLYGON(((-71, etc...)|POINT(something_else)
```

Edit: should be some update with `st_centroid(shape)` I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN centroid GEOMETRY;
UPDATE my_table SET centroid = ST_Centroid(geom);
```

If you need to be certain that the point is within the polygon however, use `ST_PointOnSurface()`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN centroid GEOMETRY;
UPDATE my_table SET centroid = ST_PointOnSurface(geom);
```

Further reading:

- [`ST_Centroid()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html)
- [`ST_PointOnSurface()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `st_PointOnSurface()`

Comment: I don't see in the documentation that `ST_PointOnSurface` will consistently return a _centroid_ within the polygon, How do you know that this is the case?

Comment: It is not a centroid, it is a point that is guaranteed to be on the polygon. Those definitions are fundamentally different.